# How can I hide one user's content from other user?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Let A and B are two users. They created account and now they have their own profile page. Both the users can add, edit information about them. 
When user A opens B's profile page the page controls for example, add, edit buttons shouldn't be visible to him.

Comment: Asp.net has a couple different authorization APIs. Here is a tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On login store the user id of the logged in user in the session. Provide a variable somewhere  accessable (like a Base class that all pages extend from). Then on that page, if the user id matches the logged in user, show the controls. Otherwise don't. Also don't forget to validate the user id on submission of the user controls as it may be possible to inject malicious data to a different user id.

Comment: You mean I need to find out the viewers IDs to compare with the session value(user id of the owner)? But How do I check the IDs who are currently viewing the profile page.

Comment: You only show the interface controls when the User who is logged in has the same ID as the page you are viewing. It's hard to give advice when I don't have an understanding of how your infrastructure works. Is your page in a public environment? Could I take a look somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I can't show it to you right now as I haven't published it yet. Anyway, I've got some idea from your last reply. Thanks for helping me.